# How can I limit the number of inupts and create unique id's for each one?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addScnt" style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Add (limit 5)</button>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to limit the creation of new inputs to 5 and create a unique id for each of them as they are generated, something like:

```
#myid1
#myid2
#myid3
#myid4
#myid5
```

This is a reproducible example only, I will need more fields for my real case.

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        if (i <= 4) { // 5 inputs limit
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i + '" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

But nothing else works. How to limit the number of entries created and assign a unique id to each of them?

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense to me. How do you decide this limit? Do you think *i* in your clickhandler is the id? Why do you want to assign a unique id to each input?

Comment: You can try to make a counter which will keep the count of created inputs. and you can use the same counter value to create a unique id for each input that is added programmatically.

Comment: @Wimanicesir This limit must be locked at a specific number (e.g. it cannot exceed 5). The maximum number of inputs created should be 5. If the user clicks again (the sixth click) no new inputs can be generated. The id's are for me to use the field values for analysis. I use the R language, I'm going to use these id's to perform calculations, I need a unique identifier for each of the inputs. They must have the same initial name, like myid.

Comment: Just fixed the open issue with the possibly repeating `id`. Thanks to @Wimanicesir for pointing that out. For now this is only a quick fix. Working with generated IDs is seldom a good idea. I prefer using class names and internal counts whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.size()` has been removed with version 3.0. It has been replaced with `jQuery.length`. I changed line three of your code and now it works, as demonstrated below:

```js
$(function() {
 let scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
 let id=0, i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;

$('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    if (i <= 4) { // Limita a 5 campos
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + (++id) + '" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + id +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="addScnt">add scent</button>
<div id="p_scents">
</div>
```

I fixed the obvious bug with possibly repeating `id`s. It is just a quick fix, but it will guarantee unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the question based on Wimanicesir's comments below the answer

This Solution also does not use jQuery incase you wanted to see a different approach  to the problem

Shown in the snippet all functionality is generated using plain vanilla java script

I've also  added the containers ID to be displayed so you can see that they all have unique identifiers regardless of what one is removed

All that is done is using one counter that increases infinitely to use as the ID and one counter that only increases to 5 to use as the count of current inputs, the `MAX` value can be changed to allow for more inputs

```js
const ADD_BUTTON = document.getElementById("AddScentButton")
const ROOT = document.getElementById("root")
const MAX = 5
const PRE_ID = "MyID-"

let input_count = 0
let input_id = 0

function createInput(id){
    let container = document.createElement("div")
    let input = document.createElement("input")
    let remove = document.createElement("a")
    let label = document.createElement("div")
    
    input.placeholder = "Input Value"

    remove.innerHTML = "Remove"
    remove.href = "javascript:;"
    remove.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        container.remove()
        input_count = input_count - 1
    })

    label.innerText = PRE_ID + id

    container.id = PRE_ID + id
    container.appendChild(label)
    container.appendChild(input)
    container.appendChild(remove)

    return(container)
}

ADD_BUTTON.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if(input_count<MAX){
        ROOT.appendChild(createInput(input_id))
        input_count = input_count + 1
        input_id = input_id + 1
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="root" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 25%;">
            <button id="AddScentButton">Add Scent</button>
        </div>
```